# Points table in a tournament

Tags: probability, permutations, puzzle

There are $7$ teams in a tournament. Each team plays exactly one match against every other team. (Total of $21$ matches). Teams get $2$ points for a win, $1$ point for a draw and $0$ points for a loss.

1) What is the minimum points for the team which finishes $3$rd on the points table.

2) What is the maximum points of the team which finishes $5$th on the points table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $42$ points available.

1) The top team can win all games $(12 pts)$ and the second team losing one game $(10 pts)$. The other $5$ teams could all draw with each other so there would be $5$ teams in $3rd$ place with $4$ points each.

2) The $6th$ and $7th$ placed teams could lose all their matches except when they play each other so they would share $2$ points $(W1, D0, L5)$ and $(W0, D0, L6)$. This leaves $40$ available points between $5$ teams. The top team could get $9$ points $(W4, D1, L1)$, the next $3$ teams $8$ points each $(W3, D2, L1)$ and the $5th$ placed team $7$ points $(W3, D1, L2)$. These win, draw and lose metrics are compatable.